# Null and delete() in regards to garbage collection

Tags: javascript, ajax, null, garbage-collection

Anyhow, If I were to write something like:

```
var h = 5;  
delete h;
```

...I'd be eliminating the reference, but not the memory.
Now, if I set the variable to `null`, would that replace the memory with the null object?

```
var h = 5;  
h = null;
```

If so, wouldn't it be better to not only `delete()` the reference, but also replace the memory with a `null` object, for better memory optimization?

```
var h = 5;  
h = null;  
delete h;
```

If I want to create a bucket-load of dynamic objects in a long and complex script, what's the best way to get rid of, or otherwise induce the garbage collector to eliminate, objects? Because in addition to just eliminating references, I had read that you could hint the collector to free memory if it was occupied by null...

Comment: What javascript implementation has a destroy operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no `destroy`. You're probably thinking about `delete`, but `delete` can't be used to delete variables, only properties. (Although currently browsers let you get away with it, with varying results.) You can delete global variables by removing them from `window`, but not locals.

Anyway you don't need to think about this sort of stuff in JavaScript. Set a variable to null and if there are no more variables pointing to the same object, it'll get garbage-collected at some point in the near future. The amount of space taken up by the record of the variable pointing to null is tiny and not worth worrying about. Unless you are making a deliberate closure it'll fall out of scope anyway when the local function exits, becoming eligable for GC.

> I had read that you could hint the collector to free memory if it was occupied by null...

Nope. You're just removing the references, the GC will pick up the now orphaned objects and free the memory at its own leisure. You don't get any say in the matter.

Comment: Would you say that there is any benefit in assigning null to your variables at the end of a function?

Comment: @Ash: no, the variables are about to fall out of scope anyway, so you gain nothing by removing the references one line earlier. Unless you are keeping a closure on the function's scope.

Comment: @bobince: That last bit "Unless you are keeping a closure on the functions scope" seems pretty important. Isn't it likely that with any callback you are going to have local variables lying around that the callback won't need when it fires. If you set them to null, the garbage collector can do it's stuff before the callback gets finished with.

Answer (score 4):

Simply drop all references to the buckload and let the garbage collection do the magic.

Comment: to mark it as dead you can use `delete container.varName;` (where container is window if global etc.)